# How to display a System.Threading.Tasks.Task<double> as a label in a WPF app?

Tags: c#, async-await

I am trying to display the result of my async Task (Below) method as a label in my WPF app.

However when I use the code

```
Label.Content = Sentiment("en", "text");
```

and run my application my labels content appears as `"System.Threading.Tasks.Task'1[System.Double]"`

Also you are not able to convert a Task into any other type as far as I am aware.

So how must I go about getting my labels content to display the Task from my sentiment method?

Thank you.

```
public async Task<double> Sentiment(string language, string text)
    {
        HttpClient _httpClient;
        _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "My Secret API Key");
        var serviceEndpoint = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/sentiment?";


        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(language) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        var request = new TextRequest();
        request.Documents.Add(new TextDocument(text, language));
        var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var result = await _httpClient.PostAsync($"{serviceEndpoint}sentiment", content).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var response = JObject.Parse(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        CatchAndThrow(response);
        return response["documents"].Children().First().Value<double>("score");
    }
```

Comment: use **await** `Label.Content = await Sentiment("en", "text"); `

Comment: Where is the label content assignment being done?

Comment: @L.B I have tried this and now the labels content doesn't change at all.

Comment: @JakeJones in case `doesn't change at all`, replace all contents within Sentiment to one statement `return "hello world"`, to determine it is those code that is not working

Comment: @LeiYang I can get it to display hello world if I change the method type to a string. Also by the way the value for the response Json is "{{  "documents": [    {      "score": 0.5,      "id": "271f4993-53df-4e5d-a863-aa0a06b2feb5"    }  ],  "errors": []}}"     The "Score" value is what we are trying to display as a label.

Comment: then it is not @L.B 's problem, it is your own responsibility to correct the inner implementation. just recommend you remove the `async Task` to common methods you're familiar then debug

Comment: Async is introduced in .net 4.5, you mean is there any wpf application does work before .net 4.5? no joking! you not only lack knowledge, you lack respect too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So how must I go about getting my labels content to display the Task from my sentiment method?

First, understand that there are two conflicting desires here:

1. It takes some time to get the data to display from the endpoint.
2. The computer must have something to display *immediately*.

The only way to properly satisfy both of these is to immediately display some kind of placeholder value and *start* the call to the endpoint, and then when the endpoint responds, *update* the display with the proper data.

Something like this would work in the simple case:

```
// Immediately, synchronously display placeholder.
Label.Content = "Loading...";

// Asynchronously update with real data.
Label.Content = await Sentiment("en", "text");
```

> I have tried this and now the labels content doesn't change at all.

Please ensure that your code is [async all the way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx), not [blocking on async code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

---

Since you are using WPF, you can also take a more advanced approach that I describe in my article on [asynchronous data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx). I have a [type `NotifyTask<T>`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async/blob/master/src/Nito.Mvvm.Async/NotifyTask.cs) which can be used as a data-bindable wrapper for `Task<T>`. You'd use it as such:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public NotifyTask<string> LabelContent { get; }
  ViewModel()
  {
    LabelContent = NotifyTask.Create(
        async () => (await Sentiment("en", "text")).ToString(),
        "Loading...");
  }
}
```

and then you'd data-bind `Label.Content` to `LabelContent.Result`. There are other properties on `NotifyTask<T>` as well (`IsNotCompleted`, `IsSuccessfullyCompleted`, `IsFaulted`) that allow you to respond to the task's state changes via data binding. E.g., you can show a busy spinner instead of `"Loading..."` if you want, or show an error if the call to the endpoint fails.

Answer (score -1):

await the result and convert it to string.

```
var result =  await Sentiment("en", "text"); 
if(result != null)
  Label.Content = result.ToString();
```